# Authoring map with advanced gradient symbol for ArcGIS web service?

Tags: arcobjects, polygon, symbology, point

I need to prepare a web service which will display the gradient of polygon points values. It has to look just like in this picture (please ignore the arrows):

[image]

Each polygon is constructed always by 9 points. The logical order of points on the polyline forming the polygon is constant. Values of points will differ. The angles and lengths of lines may differ. Basically, it will always form a trapeze.

First I played with splitting the 'large' polygon into 4 small ones using its central point. In this way, I could adjust the angles of gradients defining small polygons so that they formed this large polygonal gradient. There were however two issues - connections of the small polygons were looking rather ugly and most important - as the values of points may differ, it only suited the default scenario presented in the picture.

Comment: could you start with a distance raster from the points, thiessen polygons (to raster) and then mulitply?

Comment: Is this permanent data being served or created on the fly?

Comment: The data is located in ArcSDE DB and users are able to add new polygons via UI with ArcObjects. Sorry for no precise answer, I'm rather new to GIS.

Comment: That's ok. I've seen a few people looking for a similar effect but it would be a little difficult to create on the fly. If you are using ArcObjects to create this you would need to implement a renderer and I'm not sure on how that works on server GIS. Consider the first comment, it would probably lead you to an answer but may be too slow for your app or unimplimentable. I will have a think on this and get back later... I have to get off the 'puter now.

Comment: As we don't have a license for Spatial Analysis tool I think it is pretty much impossible to do on the server-side. I believe that even though if it would be available such processing would result in an overkill to the server. I will try to visualize this gradient on the client side using Silverlight tools. Thanks for help.

Comment: Don't give up just yet, I'm looking at IGradientFillSymbol and doing the Thiessen (Veronoi) polygons the hard(ish) way. See http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGradientFillSymbol_Interface/001w0000017w000000/